# jqGrid header and body/data column width not equal

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, jqgrid

I have issues with jqGrid column width.

Few options that I have set for my grid :
   autowidth: true,
   shrinkToFit: true,
   width : 100%,

And the change that I have done in ui.jqGrid.css is as follows:

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable {
   table-layout:auto;
   margin:0em;
} //for header - auto table layout.
```

Similarly I have done for body and footer.

Hope this helps. Please let me know in case there requires any other information.

Note:
I am using the latest jqGrid.
I referred to a similar question [jqGrid header width different from data column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805381/jqgrid-header-width-different-from-data-column-width), but it was not useful in my case.

Comment: Does anyone have a comment on this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the reason for the problem.

I had added a CSS previously for table ( meant for my custom table) and that has overridden the jQgrid CSS causing the issue.

```
    table td {
         padding: 5px;
         border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
    }

    table th {
        padding: 6px 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

So I added the specific class the above one, so that it doesn't override jqGrid. 
Sorry that I did not notice and figure it out earlier.
And also the need for change in table-layout property in jqgrid-css was not required. My motive being shrinktofit and autowidth.